# Simple friendship proof

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

I'd like to know if this is a valid proof. It is the friendship Friendship Puzzle, and i understand that while this question exists,i still want to know if my method is valid

The theorem is that:

> At any party of two or more people, show that there are always two
> people with exactly the same number of friends at the party.

My attempt:

Assume the party has n people.
There two possible cases, a person, x,  has at least one friend, or a person has no friends.

case 1: at least one friend.
Then x can have up to n-1 friends. Since everyone at the party can have up to n-1 friends, and the party has n people, by the pigeonhole principle, at least two people have n-1 friends.

case 2:

then for n-1 people at the party (excluding x), everyone can have up to n-2 friends (excluding themselves and x). Similary by the Pigeonhole principle, at least two people have the same number of friends.

We are done.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the PP for case 2? How many pigeons and how many holes do you have? $\quad$ Separately,  the conclusion that "at least two people have n-2 friends" seems very surprising to me. Maybe there is a typo?  $\quad$ FWIW You could induct on $n$ to deal with this $n-1$ case. (just be careful of your base case.)

Comment: for n-1 others at the party, they can have up to n-2 friends. by PP, at least 2 people have the same number of friends.

Comment: They can have 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-2 friends right? How many holes is that? This is why I phrased my question as asking for the number of pigeons and holes, so that I can track exactly what you are thinking.

Comment: is it n-2 holes? 
edit: i am modelling the # of friends as holes and people at the party as pigeons

Comment: In case 2, a person could have 0, 1, 2, ..., n-2, friends, can't they? If so, isn't there $n-1$ holes?  How did you get $n-2$ holes? Can you list them out?

Comment: i thought there had to be one more hole than pigeon for the principle to work,
and if people == pigeons = n-2 then one more is n-1?

Comment: Right, so you have n-1 people and n-1 holes (possible values of friends), hence can't quite apply PP directly to this case (which was my point, and why I was asking you to elaborate on how you did the PP).  Note that this is similar when we had $n$ people, and naively there were $n$ holes.

Comment: i understand. i will try again, thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, I got OP to realize that in their case 2, they have $n-1$ pigeons and $n-1$ holes, so can't quite apply Pigeonhole principle and get the stated result.

I suggested that to complete the proof, they could proceed by induction, or proceed in a similar manner (which would essentially be induction).